# A "one time" if condition

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make an if condition that will only work once.
Is there a way to do so WITHOUT the use of a global boolean variable?

```
if (A CONDITION THAT WILL BE RIGHT ONLY ONE TIME)
{
//Stuff...
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `boolean`?

Comment: once every time the app launches? Or once, just one time and then never again?

Comment: @pbabcdefp You're right, I could use a boolean variable, but I wanted to know if there's a solution that works only within the method (nothing personal against globals..).

Comment: @ezocoding once every time the app launches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is dispatch_once what you need?

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once (&onceToken, ^{
    // Do some work that happens once
});
```

But actually, onceToken is static.